# Missing hat in the list

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

This [guy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) have [5 hats](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com) but it reflects only 4, hope this is bug.

Confused how he opened the closed question.

[image]

Comment: Hard refresh (ctrl+F5 on most browsers). It's cached.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 hmm nothing happening check here http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Which hat is supposedly missing?

Comment: Check the image batman is there!

Comment: @Doorknob冰 Actually this is one of the few times that [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) is wrong.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Note the fine print: "*Advice may be invalid due to caching*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Community User's hat rack](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community#winter-bash), you can see that it has earned the Batman hat only on travel.se and arqade.se, and not Drupal Answers.

[image: Community has earned Batman on travel and arqade]

A user, including Community, can wear a hat earned *anywhere* on the network anywhere on the network.